# How to get return value from SQL Server stored procedure in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API. I tried to get the return value from a SQL Server stored procedure.

This is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> Login(EmployeeDO _loginDO)
{
    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RetnParam",  ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LoginId", _loginDO.empno));
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LoginPwd", _loginDO.password));

    string StoredProc = "exec PR_ABCXYZ " +
                "@LoginId = " + _loginDO.empno + "," +
                "@LoginPwd = '" + _loginDO.password + "'";

    var result = await  DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(StoredProc);

    bool ret = Convert.ToBoolean(result);

    return ret;
}
```

The result always returns -1.

Comment: `exec PR_ABCXYZ` should be `exec @RetnParam = PR_ABCXYZ`

Comment: Hi Dale, It throws an error "Must declare the scalar variable "@RetnParam"."

Comment: Maybe because you're not passing your parameters list to ExecuteSqlRawAsync?

Comment: And you are using your parameters incorrectly, you don't assign them again when you build your SP string. `var StoredProc = "exec @RetnParam = PR_ABCXYZ @LoginId, @LoginPwd`.

Comment: Don't use `DbContext`, use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` directly.

Comment: @DaleK Not if you use `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: Ya Dale, I didn't use the Parameter variable. i directly assign values in StoredProc

Comment: By "return value" do you mean the T-SQL `PROCEDURE` **return code** (which is always an `int` value), or do you mean an `OUTPUT @parameter`? (It is commonplace for the return-code to be abused to output data, which people shouldn't be doing, imo)

Comment: @NagaRaj That's not how `SqlParameter` works: _you're using it incorrectly_ **and** you're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: "I didn't use the Parameter variable. i directly assign values in StoredProc" - which is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: It looks like you're storing passwords in plaintext in your database **YOU MUST NOT DO THAT!**

Comment: I am returning int value as Return. If Success 1 or 0

Comment: No Dai i am storing passwords as encrypted one in Database.

Comment: Any reference examples?

Comment: Loads... this question is asked frequently... a quick google should find you many examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public async Task<bool> Login(EmployeeDO _loginDO)
    {
        var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        // **param name should not have @ here **
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("RetnParam",  ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LoginId", _loginDO.empno));
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LoginPwd", _loginDO.password));

        string StoredProc = "exec @RetnParam = PR_ABCXYZ @LoginId @LoginPwd"; // **No need to concatenate @LoginId and @LoginPwd values here**

        await  DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(StoredProc, parameters); // **pass parameters here**
        bool ret = Convert.ToBoolean(parameters[0].Value); // **use RetnParam value
        return ret;
    }
```